# React: Render Array of Incoming Websocket Messages

Tags: reactjs, websocket, react-hooks

I've opened a websocket to receive incoming messages. I want to render the messages as they arrive (or as quickly as possible). I want to push each new message to the front of an array, and rerender that array on every new message.

Here is the Custom Hook component that will return the array to be rendered:

```
export default function usePendingTransactions() {
  const [pendingData, setPendingData] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const WebSocket = require('isomorphic-ws');
    const ws = new WebSocket("wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/APIKEY");
    ws.onopen = function open() {
      ws.send('{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_subscribe","params":["newPendingTransactions"],"id":1}')
    };
    ws.onmessage = function incoming(data) {
      var response = JSON.parse(data.data)
      setPendingData(pendingData => [response.result, ...pendingData])
    }
  }, []);
  return pendingData
```

As written, the first message received is rendered correctly. Then only undefined objects are pushed to the array using the setPendingData hook. Can anyone see why my response variable is undefined after the first message?

Comment: have you tried to check what you have in the response constant?

Comment: Yes, the very first response is as expected (transaction hash), but every response after that is an undefined object.